# Adjektiv für Dinge aus Bangladesch

Tags: adjective

Die Leute aus Bangladesch werden Bengalen genannt. *(**EDIT**: Das stimmt nicht, wie in den Kommentaren erwähnt.)*

Bengalen ist eine Region in Indien. Das dazugehörige Adjektiv ist "bengalisch".

Was ist das zu Bangladesch gehörige Adjektiv?

Beispiel: Ein Mädchen aus Bengalen ist ein bengalisches Mädchen. Ein Knabe aus Bangladesch ist ein [?] Knabe.

Einschlägige Recherchen dazu (vor allem in Online-Foren) haben bisher leider nur uneindeutige Ergebnisse hervorgebracht.

Comment: Nämlich welche? Und bitte nie mehr als ein Fragezeichen. Danke.

Comment: Mich verwirrt, dass Leute aus Bangladesch Bengalen heißen sollen. Bengalen ist eine Region, die mehr umfasst als das heutige Bangladesch... Flüchtigkeitsfehler?

Comment: Man würde übrigens, selbst wenn es theoretisch oder außenamtlich das Wort "bangladeschisch" gibt, für einen Knaben aus Bangladesch üblicherweise einfach dies sagen: *ein Knabe aus Bangladesch*, einfach um das komplizierte und unübliche Wort zu umgehen.

Comment: @userunknown auf verschiedenen Foren mit einiges an Durchgeklicke und schlussendlich frustriertem Schliessen des Browsers (wobei Cookies und History gelöscht wurden), darum habe keine bisherigen Quellen nennen können. Ja, das mit den Bengalen und Bangladesch basiert wohl auf einer falschen, jedoch landläufigen, Annahme. Auch ich wurde davon nicht verschont. Fragen fragen hilft eben, wie wir nun alle gemerkt haben. Das mit den multiplen Satzzeichen ist mir [durchaus bewusst](http://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Multiple_exclamation_marks), sie dienten mir jedoch bloss zur Verlängerung der Klammer.

Comment: @thymaro:   Lösung des Bangalen-Problems vielleicht: Wenn alle Leute, die aus der Region Bengalen kommen, Bengalen genannt werden können, dann kann man auch alle Bangladescher Bengalen nennen, da Bangladesch ein Teil der Region Bengalen ist - wenn ich die Geographie richtig im Kopf habe. Dann wäre *Bengalen* so ein Wort wie *Alpenbewohner*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Auch wenn es vielleicht seltsam klingt, ist das Adjektiv zu Bangladesch

> bangladeschisch

Bei dieser Meinung sind sich alle einschlägigen Quellen einig: [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/bangladeschisch), [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bangladeschisch), [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/bangladeschisch?lookup=caseSensitive).

*Hinweis*: Die Grundannahme der Frage "die Leute aus Bangladesch werden Bengalen genannt" ist nicht zutreffend. Die Bewohner von Bangladesch werden

> Bangladescher

genannt. (Quelle: [Länderverzeichnis für den amtlichen Gebrauch in der Bundesrepublik Deutschland](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/blob/215256/e505c18e9cd162813a29f4e5a4ec8e07/laenderverzeichnis-data.pdf) des Auswärtigen Amts.)

Comment: joa, wenn man die Begriffe nicht vorderhand kennt und sie nicht als solches eingibt, ist es _etwas_ schwieriger, darauf zu kommen. Danke dafür.

Comment: Es ist nützlich, daran zu denken, daß der indische Bundesstaat Westbengalen, wie sein Name andeutet, zu Bengalen gehört. In ihm wird überwiegend Bengalisch gesprochen. Diese Sprache heißt auf Bengalisch _Bangla_. _Bangla Desh_ bedeutet _Land des Bangla_.